# Secure stored procedure update

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have stored procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[myDbProcedure]
@ID int

AS
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [myDB] WHERE @ID = [ID])
UPDATE [myDB]
SET [count] = [count] - 1
, [paymentCount]  = [paymentCount]  + 1
WHERE @ID = [ID] 

END
```

Now I want secure if 100 people at same time update table any information dont missed

Comment: When you say secure, do you mean you don't want the data to become inconcistent?  If that is the case, then you want to look into Transactions...

Comment: @Penfold no if 100 people at same time update table updates only to who was the first . I need some logic which will update table for 100 people (which update at same time) step by step

Comment: what is the need of `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [myDB] WHERE @ID = [ID])`

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if I fully understood what you require:

```
Begin Tran
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [myDB] WHERE @ID = [ID])
    UPDATE [myDB]
    SET [count] = [count] - 1
    , [paymentCount]  = [paymentCount]  + 1
    WHERE @ID = [ID] 
Commit
```

You can also consider removing the if, once that update will only happen if the register actually exists. This way you'll have just the update which by nature runs in the context of a transaction. Consider looking into isolation levels (from comment: set transaction isolation level serializable).

Comment: thank you for answering, if 100 people at same time update table updates only to who was the first . I need some logic which will update table for 100 people (which update at same time) step by step

Comment: You might want to look at method 4 here: http://michaeljswart.com/2011/09/mythbusting-concurrent-updateinsert-solutions/